# Count the values and apply a condition based on the values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
select new_id_after_comparison, count(new_id_after_comparison) as Number_of_complaints
from CRM_Registered
group by new_id_after_comparison
```

[image: These results]

**I also want to set the query as a condition, if the value of Number_of_complaints is greater than 1, put in the query a value of "1 left" or else put a value of "0"**

**I want the results to be as follows**

[image]

Comment: Where do the additional rows come from in your desired results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a `case` expression:

```
select new_id_after_comparison, count(*)as Number_of_complaints,
       (case when count(*) = 1 then '0'
             else '1 left'
        end) as test
from CRM_Registered
group by new_id_after_comparison
```